# which formats are supported by libvlc_media_player_set_time

Tags: c++, macos, vlc

I'm writing a movie player using VLC engine on Mac Os but I encounter a little problem :

On the `VLC` doc you can read about this (`libvlc_media_player_set_time()`) function :

> > Set the movie time (in ms).
> >
> > This has no effect if no media is being played. Not all formats and protocols support this.

But I can't find any information about the formats and protocols supported. As my application is not very smooth, I was wondering if this might be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, this works for virtually all local files (except for MPEG TS encapsulated streams in some corner cases). For networking, this depends on the availability of seeking - i.e. you cannot seek in live streams as they are coming in as it is happening. Same for multicast streams. However, it works just fine for VoD.

However, this should not be related to your app being smooth or not, so please elaborate if this answer doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: In fact I had to finish my work for today so I changed my mind on VLC and now use FFMPEG which is more appropriate for my goal. Thank you anyway!